# Update the attributes of the Django Models.py from views.py

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am working on a booking system project (Django) and I want to make seats decreasing by 1 every time a user books a ticket I made seats as a variable in the train class in the models file and I made a function which decreases the seats by 1 in the same file but I don't know how or where to call it.

Comment: Can you share some codes on what you have done so far?

Comment: You should share some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) to avoid a [possible race condition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#avoiding-race-conditions-using-f) when subtracting the number of seats.

```
from django.db.models import F
from myproject.models import Train

train = Train.objects.get(some_train_id)
train.seats = F('seats') - 1
train.save()
```

What this will do is use database semantics to decrement the value. That way, even if you have people take up a seat at the same time, you'll set the correct number in the db.

You can call this from almost anywhere. Typically it will be a view in your Django application.